# Definition of ExecCommand function for bold?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, execcommand

ExecCommand offers a way to bold text inside iFrame, make it italic, underline it etc.

But it's missing an option to create `<cite>` or `<strong>` or `<em>` (there is `formatBlock` but only for block elements and not inline ones).

I'd like to use ExecCommand function for creating `<cite>` - is there any way to achieve this? And obviously I want to maintain flawless parsing like in case of `bold` and not something like `surroundContents` which will fail when you use it twice on the same selection.

I'm looking for a definition of ExecCommand bold command or a way to use existing commants to flawlessly add `<cite>`. Any suggestions? I couldn't extract it from browser's functions. It says "native code" when I try to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see that CKEditor was mentioned in one of previous comments :) So this is how we handle executing commands:

- We do **everything** manually. As you can see DOM API isn't sufficient and implementations differ between browsers, so I guess (but I haven't checked this) that HTML containing some text with applied styles in one browser won't work in other (because one browser applied `strong` and second `b` or `span` with inline style).
- First of all we need custom [Range](http://nightly-v4.ckeditor.com/ckeditor_api/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range) and [Selection](http://nightly-v4.ckeditor.com/ckeditor_api/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.selection) implementations. You can't use them, but there's a cool [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) lib.
- Next component that you need is set of methods for applying, removing and checking styles. Here's [our impl](http://nightly-v4.ckeditor.com/ckeditor_api/#!/api/CKEDITOR.style).
- And the last component is trivial - [custom commands](http://nightly-v4.ckeditor.com/ckeditor_api/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-execCommand), because it's convenient to mimic W3C's APIs and ideas.

Comment: Great! Thank you :) I've got working editor already but a way to unify `bold` to always use `strong` or `b` is something I'm interested in, too. That's a lot of code to be checked and there not much info on `ExecCommand` on the Internet. Thank you for creating Open Source software :)

Answer (score 0):

I researched this problem a year ago and could not found any solution except using regex instead EC on nested tags. I developted my text editor without using ExecCommand.

Comment: I'm facing this problem right now. Bold etc. work excellent but it would be cool to add all similar HTML tags. Did you manage to create `<cite>` in your editor? How did you use regex (if it's not a secret or copyrighted work)?

Comment: its copyrighted but i can advise you to dig up the files of CKEditor.

Comment: Thanks :) I will. I already checked YUI rich text editor's code but investigating this takes days. They create browser-specific code and include tons of exceptions. Ready solutions are the ones that I prefer where possible. Thanks again!!